# Load data from XML to selectfield in a form in sencha touch 2

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, combobox, sencha-touch-2, store

> I want to populate data from an XML file to a selectfield in a form in sencha 2. how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a combination of
[Ext.data.reader.Xml](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml) for getting the xml data into a store and then set up your selectfield as:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',

    placeHolder: 'No options',   //what to display when store is empty

    store: MyStore,              //name of the store instance

    valueField:'assessorId',     //field in the store record that you want as
                                 //the 'value' of the item

    displayField:'assessorName', //field in the store record that will be 
                                 //displayed as text in the select item
}
```

Hope this helps you on the way!

Comment: Really, a downvote? What is wrong with my answer? The question itself is poor at best (shows no indication of own research), so an answer that points the user in the right direction is sufficient I think.

Comment: Thanks .. this is working with Json(with some modifications) but with XML nothing is happening. Nothing means no error & no positive result.

Comment: If you have tried a solution you really should edit your post with some code. That way it would be much easier for others to see how you are doing things and what may be the error.